# SendGrid: Sending Bulk Email results in BadRequest Error

Tags: c#, email, sendgrid, bulk

I am trying to send bulk email using the below code.

We are maintaining our own email templates, which I'm loading with the AddContent() method.  Since this is a template, I use the substitutions to add the common fields.  This seems to work fine, but I get no emails when I add the personalizations.

Am I using this correctly?
Am I doing anything wrong?

```
//  START OF SAMPLE CODE //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var sendGridClient = new SendGridClient(_configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureFunctionsJobHost:SendGridApiKey"));

var msg = new SendGridMessage();
msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress(no-reply@example.com, asset.CompanyName));
msg.SetSubject(asset.Subject);
msg.AddContent(MimeType.Html, asset.Asset);
                
msg.AddSubstitution("[vanity_url]", asset.VanityUrl);
msg.AddSubstitution("[tech_support]", asset.TechSupport);
msg.AddSubstitution("[strdate]", asset.strdate?.ToLongDateString());
msg.AddSubstitution("[strtime]", asset.strtime);
msg.AddSubstitution("[time_zone]", asset.TimeZone);
msg.AddSubstitution("[meet_id]", asset.EventId.ToString());
msg.AddSubstitution("[title]", asset.EventName);
msg.AddSubstitution("[company_id]", asset.CompanyId.ToString());
msg.AddSubstitution("[authentication]", "");
msg.AddSubstitution("[company_name]", asset.CompanyName);

var personalizations = new List<Personalization>();
foreach (var a in attendees)
{
         var per = new Personalization();
          per.Tos = new List<EmailAddress>(new[] { new EmailAddress(a.Email, a.FullName) });
          per.Substitutions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
          per.Substitutions.Add("[fullname]", a.FullName);
          per.Substitutions.Add("[email]", a.Email);
          personalizations.Add(per);
}
msg.Personalizations = personalizations;

await sendGridClient.SendEmailAsync(msg);

//  END OF SAMPLE CODE //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Are Substitutions and Personalizations mutually exclusive?

I do get emails without the personalizations when I add a destination email using msg.AddTo().  When I remove the AddTo() and add personalizations, it results in a BadRequest Error.

EDIT:  With personalizations added to the SendGridMessage object, I do NOT get any emails whether I have msg.AddTo() or not.

EDIT:  Here's the Response I get from this specific sample of code:

```
// START OF RESPONSE //////////////////////////////////// 

BODY:
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent

HEADERS:
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 19 Jul 2023 15:16:46 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=600; includeSubDomains 

ISSUCCESSSTATUSCODE:
False 

STATUSCODE:
BadRequest

// END OF RESPONSE ////////////////////////////////////
```

(Response does not appear useful to my untrained eye)

EDIT:  Here's the Body of the Response,

[image]

EDIT:  Looks like I'm getting somewhere...  these are the results of inspecting the Response.HttpContent further.

One of my POC's returned:
{"errors":[{"message":"The subject is required. You can get around this requirement if you use a template with a subject defined or if every personalization has a subject defined.","field":"subject","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.subject"}]}

Another POC returned:
{"errors":[{"message":"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked","field":null,"help":null}]}

I managed to get my third POC working by first using the white-listed domain in my "from" email address, and second, but changing all of my personalized "from" email addresses to use the same domain as the main/top-level "from" email address.

Regarding the "subject missing" error, I first thought it wasn't really required whan I say it was missing in my payload, and I am explicitly setting it with SetSubject().  I will investigate further.

Comment: Does the error response give you any details?

Comment: @Swimburger - I added the Response Object to my original question

Comment: Is it possible to get the content of the body? It's printing the type name of the body ATM, not the body content. I'm wondering if there's a more useful error message inside the body.

Comment: @Swimburger - doesn't look like anything useful in the body.

Comment: The `HttpConnectionResponseContent` is empty?

Comment: @Swimburger - no, the body property is not empty, but it looks useless.  I added a screenshot of the watch.  It looks like it just contains the header.

Comment: Looks like there is JSON content in there, based on the headers and content length.
Use `ReadAsStringAsync` to get the contents from the body and share it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync?view=net-7.0

Comment: @Swimburger - I fixed POC#1 by correcting the "from" email addresses as mentioned above.  POC#2 (code shown above in post) sets the subject in code, yet it is still blank.  That appears to be causing that error.  POC#3 error is displayed above.  Not even sure where to start with that one.

Comment: Can you log the SendGrid API key to verify that it is correctly configured? Make sure you're using the key, not the key ID. Regarding the subject, you either have to configure it at the message level, the personalization level, or use a dynamic email template.